# Error from Importing Pandas

Tags: pandas, python-import, importerror

I use pandas regularly.  I restarted my computer recently and now I get the following error every time I try to import pandas.  This does not happen with other packages.  Any suggestions?

```
import pandas as pd
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\UserName\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

File "", line 1, in 
    import pandas as pd

File "C:\Users\UserName\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas__init__.py", line 42, in 
    from pandas.core.api import *

File "C:\Users\UserName\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 10, in 
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper

File "C:\Users\UserName\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 49, in 
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame

File "C:\Users\UserName\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4262
    df                        ignore_failures=ignore_failures)

Comment: Have you tried `conda remove pandas` followed by `conda install pandas` to remove and reinstall pandas?

Comment: I did but now I get "ImportError: cannot import name 'isna'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:  I uninstalled anaconda and reinstalled and everything is now working.